Parsing Lists: BIO 2024 Q2
I was practising question 2a of the British Informatics Olympiad 2024 past paper.

In this task you will manipulate lists of integers to create new lists. There are three fundamental lists that you will start from:

E — the list of even integers, in order, starting with 2;
O — the list of odd integers, in order, starting with 1;
T — the list of integers, in order, where each one occurs the same number of times in the list as its value, starting 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, …

Given a list L, L[i] indicates the value in the ith position of L. If L and R are two lists, L on the left and R on the right, when combined they are replaced by list C where the ith position of C is R[L[R[i]]].
I.e. we ﬁnd a value in list R, use it to ﬁnd a value in list L and then use that value to ﬁnd a ﬁnal value in list R.
For example, if we combine O (on the left) and E:

The 1st value in E is 2, the 2nd value in O is 3, and the 3rd value in E is 6;
The 2nd value in E is 4, the 4th value in O is 7, and the 7th value in E is 14;
The combined sequence is 6, 14, …

A description, giving details on the required manipulations, contains lists as well as brackets.
Lists in the description will be combined until there is only a single list remaining.
Where part of a description lies between brackets, it is treated as an independent description and that part will be manipulated (without combination with external lists) until reduced to a single list, at which point those brackets are then removed.
When a description contains no brackets, the leftmost two lists are repeatedly combined forming a new description, until a single list remains.
For example:

E is a description of a single list, so there is nothing further to do;
OE involves a single combination leading to 6, 14, 22, 30, 38, …
E(OE) will be the combination of E with OE, i.e. 94, 222, 350, …
EOT is manipulated by ﬁrst combining EO, then combining the resulting list with T, and is equivalent to (EO)T.



Write a program that calculates the ith value in a fully manipulated description.
Your program should input a string d of up to 12 characters (E, O, T or brackets)
followed by i (1 ≤ i ≤ 260). You will not be required to access any value over 261.
You should output the ith value in the fully manipulated description d.

I wrote this code (It is divided into different files so that I can reuse parts for Q2b/Q2c):
q2.h
#ifndef Q2_H
#define Q2_H

#include <functional>
#include <cstdint>

std::uint64_t E(std::uint64_t n);
std::uint64_t O(std::uint64_t n);
std::uint64_t T(std::uint64_t n);
std::function<std::uint64_t(std::uint64_t)> combined(std::function<std::uint64_t(std::uint64_t)> f, std::function<std::uint64_t(std::uint64_t)> g);

#endif

q2.cc
#include <functional>
#include <cstdint>

#include "q2.h"

std::uint64_t E(std::uint64_t n) {
    return n * 2;
}

std::uint64_t O(std::uint64_t n) {
    return n * 2 - 1;
}

std::uint64_t T(std::uint64_t n) {
    std::uint64_t x = 0;

    while (n > 0) {
        for (std::uint64_t i = 0; i <= x; ++i) --n;
        ++x;
    }

    return x;
}

std::function<std::uint64_t(std::uint64_t)> combined(std::function<std::uint64_t(std::uint64_t)> f, std::function<std::uint64_t(std::uint64_t)> g) {
    return [f, g](std::uint64_t n) { return g(f(g(n))); };
}

q2a.cc
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>

#include "q2.h"

std::function<std::uint64_t(std::uint64_t)> parse_char(char c) {
    switch (c) {
        case 'E': return E;
        case 'O': return O;
        case 'T': return T;
        default:
            std::cerr << "Illegal value for argument c: '" << c << "'\n";
            exit(1);
    }
}

std::string get_first_bracketed_substr(std::string str) {
    int end = str.find(")");
    return str.substr(1, end - 1);
}

std::function<std::uint64_t(std::uint64_t)> parse_string(std::string str) {
    std::function<std::uint64_t(std::uint64_t)> fun;
    int i;

    if (str[0] == '(') {
        std::string substring = get_first_bracketed_substr(str);
        fun = parse_string(substring);
        i = substring.length() + 2;
    } else {
        fun = parse_char(str[0]);
        i = 1;
    }

    for (; i < str.length(); ++i) {
        if (str[i] == ')') continue;
        else if (str[i] == '(') {
            std::string substring = str.substr(i);
            substring = get_first_bracketed_substr(substring);
            fun = combined(fun, parse_string(substring));

            i += substring.length() + 1;
        } else {
            fun = combined(fun, parse_char(str[i]));
        }
    }
    return fun;
}

int main() {
    std::string str;
    int i;

    std::cout << "Enter input:\n";
    std::cin >> str >> i;

    auto fun = parse_string(str);

    std::cout << fun(i) << '\n';
}

Example run:
Enter input:
E(OE) 3
350

(More test cases can be found in the mark scheme.)
In testing, the code gave correct answers in a reasonable time except when the sequence contained T - as its logic is not as simple as that of E or O, it took a lot more time - but I don't know where to start in optimizing it.
I would be grateful to hear of any improvements or optimizations that could be made to this code.

EDIT
After posting, I found a better way to implement T from this post. It now reads:
std::uint64_t T(std::uint64_t n) {
    return std::round(std::sqrt(2 * n));
}

It now gives all the answers in a reasonable time.

It's too clean for competition programming code. Most people will do something like typedef long long ll and be done with it. In fact most code wouldn't ever use std::string and just use vector.

@qwr could you elaborate? Are you saying that I should do those things next time I do past papers?

No you should absolutely not do those things. I can’t tell whether that’s terrible advice or just supposed to be a bad joke, but either way, you should ignore that comment.

It depends on what you're going for. The purpose of these programming competitions is on the algorithm, not on writing nice code. Of course you can still write nice code, but it looks too verbose to me for stuff meant to be written as fast as possible.

This is clear, well-presented code; much better than the thrown-together hacks often seen as programming-challenge entries.
We could perhaps make it even clearer by giving a name to std::function<std::uint64_t(std::uint64_t)>:
using IntegerTransformU64 = std::function<std::uint64_t(std::uint64_t)>;

IntegerTransformU64 combined(IntegerTransformU64 f, IntegerTransformU64 g) {
    return [f, g](std::uint64_t n) { return g(f(g(n))); };
}

Even though we chose quite a long name, it's now much clearer that both arguments and the return value are of the same type.

Remember that std::uint64_t is an optional type - portable code would likely use std::uint_fast64_t instead.

We have a type mismatch here:
    int end = str.find(")");

Simply changing to auto end fixes this.
Similarly, int i in parse_string ought to be std::size_t i.

Good practice when including headers is to include the header being implemented first, before standard library headers.  This helps us avoid accidentally depending on a standard header already being included.

It's nice to see some error checking here:

    default:
        std::cerr << "Illegal value for argument c: '" << c << "'\n";
        exit(1);


I'm guessing that's meant to be std::exit(), from <cstdlib>.  However, I would try to avoid exiting - I'd prefer to throw an exception here, which we could handle in main() to print the exception and return EXIT_FAILURE.  That gives us much more freedom to reuse this code.

There's no error checking here, though:

    std::cin >> str >> i;


Nor is there any checking that i is within range (switching to an unsigned type would fix that, I think - and std::uint64_t is a natural choice given that's what we immediately widen it to).

The functions in q2a.cc (other than main(), of course) should be declared with internal linkage (static keyword, or anonymous namespace).

Instead of passing std::string by value between functions, we can pass as const reference.  Better would be to pass std::string_view, which has a much cheaper substr() operation.  And in parse_string(), we could just adjust the string-view until it's empty, rather than maintaining the index i.
That can make for a simpler implementation (though note that this is recursive rather than iterative, to avoid the need to special-case the first character):
static const IntegerTransformU64 identity = [](auto i){return i;};

static auto parse_string(std::string_view str)
{
    if (str.empty()) {
        return identity;
    }

    if (str.front() == '(') {
        auto end = str.find(')');
        auto substring = str.substr(1, end - 1);
        return combined(parse_string(substring),
                        parse_string(str.substr(end+1)));
    } else {
        return combined(parse_char(str.front()),
                        parse_string(str.substr(1)));
    }
}

